# Visual Studio Publishing Profile wont accept Install url with spaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, clickonce, .net-8.0, publish-profiles

Working with C# .Net8 Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.8.6.  We converted our application from .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net8(I don't ever want to do that again).  Publishing from .Net Framework 4.8 didn't have this issue. We use ClickOnce.

I have to publish to a location that I don't have control of(I can't change the path itself) and it has spaces in some of the folders in the path.

When I try to add this path as the install location in a publishing profile Visual Studio complains that it needs a complete URL... when I remove the spaces from the path the error goes away and it seems to be happy.

How do I get around this? I need the install location to be this path with the spaces... is there a different way to type it? quotes?

I didn't try anything other than removing the spaces.  I don't want to publish without knowing that how I fixed it will still install from the same location.

Comment: What happens if you replace spaces with `%20`?

Comment: That's what my coworkers suggested I do and it does fix the problem.  It seems like visual studio doesn't really like it and tries to crash when I make that change but if you can get the change in and saved it does work.

Comment: Urls cannot have spaces. That's not [RFC compliant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738). If your coworkers configured this, they MUST follow the RFC

Answer (score 0):

Working with some other team members this is what ended up being the solution.

replace the space in the path with %20

in Example:
https:www.Some Website.com/files
becomes
https:www.Some%20Website.com/files

Why this is all of a sudden an issue after switching to .Net... Idk.  Another thing I wanna note is that in trying to do the %20 change visual studio actually crashed on me a couple of times. To get around that I put in a working path without spaces so I could get my publishing profile all filled out and saved it. Then went back in and as fast as I could I pasted in the new path with the %20's and clicked finish.  This seemed to work for me and I had no issues publishing with the profile after that.